# FileManager memory leak

Tags: swift, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsfilemanager

I have a memory leak problem with FileManager.
My code is like this;

```
    func saveImageToDocumentDirectory(image: UIImage, name: String, then handler: @escaping () -> Void) {
     DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        autoreleasepool {
            let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
            let fileName = name // name of the image to be saved
            let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
            if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.2),!FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path){
                do {
                    try data.write(to: fileURL)
                    handler()
                    print("file saved")
                } catch {
                    handler()
                    print("error saving file:", error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After the handler response it does not remove from memory. For example It starts with 60MB then It rises 190MB, when all images saved, It does not down to 60MB.

Comment: What's in `handler`? It's possible that you have a strong ownership loop i.e. if `handler` is owned by an object and the object is referenced in `handler` (most commonly as `self`).